# Is a model including a square root of a variable linear in the parameters?

Tags: data-transformation, linear-model, assumptions, definition

Is the model
$$
y = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 + \sqrt x + \varepsilon
$$
linear in parameters? ( $\varepsilon$ is the error term.)

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  I'm guessing it is.  If so, here's a hint.  The gamma's are the parameters.

Comment: I think this may be written incorrectly.  I believe it should be $\gamma_1\sqrt{x}$, correct?

Comment: @StatsStudent: Homework or not, we need to be told what the free parameters are, especially as the model is unidentifiable as it stands.

Comment: Fair enough @Scortchi.

Comment: @StatsStudent, that is a reasonable guess. The model as stated is clearly unidentifiable. However, I just added $\TeX$, I didn't add the "$+$".

Comment: @gung, you are correct.  I saw that when I reviewed the edit.  I edited my response to you likely while you were posting.  Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem, @StatsStudent, it was an important thing to mention.

Comment: In any case, the concept of "linear in the parameters" is explained [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59782), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92065), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76954), 
[here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71437), [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62506), & [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100653).